# Фильтрация таблицы по клику на кнопку

Tags: excel, макросы

Добавил в документ кнопку с событием на Щелчок.
По щелчку мне нужно задать фильтрацию на колонку AO в Лист4.
Эта колонка принимает только три значения Ложь, Истина и (Пустые). Мне нужно скрыть только те строки, которые Ложь.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать, в макросах не шарю.

Comment: Фильтровать на месте? Установите фильтр и запишите действия макрорекодером. А потом покажите сюда. Подправим :)

Comment: О там есть запись? но я короче её уже сам вывел) сейчас в ответы кину

Answer (score 0):

Помучился, но всё-таки вывел формулу

```
Sub Собратьдоговор_Щелчок()
    Лист4.Range("$AO$1:$AO$464").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="ИСТИНА"
End Sub
```